# Swift, ios 10 UIButton Border

Tags: swift, animation, uibutton, border

I was developing in Swift 3 and I had a little problem with a UIButton. I will try to explain my problem. First I created my UIButton:

```
let Button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "button"), for: .normal)        
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    //button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()
```

After in the viewDidLoad I implemented the action:

```
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonUnpressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

In which "favButtonPressed" is a function with no importance
The problem is when I touch the button the border doesn't get unhighlighted as the image or the text does. It is a detail of little importance but quite annoying.

I have tried changing the alpha value when pressed and re-change it but the problem is i dont know how to animate it to make the animation for 2 seconds (the next line of code doesnt work, it does change the color but not during 2 seconds):

```
func buttonUnpressed(){
    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    })
}
```

The question; is there any way of adding the border to the UIButton "total behavior" of highlighting and unhighlighting when pressed?

Excuse me for my english if there are some expression or gramatical faults.

EDIT
I tried with this function:

```
 func buttonUnpressed(){
    button.alpha = 0.2
    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.button.alpha = 1
    }
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
}
```

there is a weird highlight of the image but now it works more or less.

Comment: favButtonUnpressed?  Your button selector says "buttonUnpressed."

Comment: That won't work.  You are not removing the original layer when the user taps the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find the final answer.
Thanks to krotov who tried to help!

```
 class BorderButton: UIButton {

 override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

var colorPast: Bool = true

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isHighlighted && colorPast {
            borderDissapear(highlighted: isHighlighted)
            colorPast = false
        } else if !isHighlighted && !colorPast {
            borderDissapear(highlighted: isHighlighted)
            colorPast = true
        }
    }
}

func borderDissapear (highlighted: Bool) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
    animation.duration = 0.1
    animation.autoreverses = false
    animation.repeatCount = 1
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    if highlighted {
        animation.fromValue = self.layer.borderColor?.copy(alpha: 1)
        animation.toValue = self.layer.borderColor?.copy(alpha: 0.3)
    } else if !highlighted {
        animation.fromValue = self.layer.borderColor?.copy(alpha: 0.3)
        animation.toValue = self.layer.borderColor?.copy(alpha: 1)
    }
    self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "borderColor")
}
}
```

Comment: Note that there are a number of functions that allow you to set colors or titles based on the state of the button - you used one of them in your initial question( for example `func setBackgroundImage(_ image: UIImage?, for state: UIControlState)`). Instead of passing in .normal for state, pass in .highlighted. Whenever the button enters the state you specified, you will see it change.

Comment: @swillsea i know! the problem is the controlState is only useful for the image or title

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension to animate change of border color:

```
extension UIButton {
    func borderColorAnimation(from: CGColor, to: CGColor, duration: CFTimeInterval) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        animation.fromValue = from
        animation.toValue = to
        animation.duration = duration
        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "borderColor")
        self.layer.borderColor = to
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
let fromColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
let toColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
self.button.borderColorAnimation(from: fromColor, to: toColor, duration: 200)
```

Comment: Thanks! But it actually didnt worked for me.At first it didnt even change color. After changing the key to "layer.borderColor" it did change the color, but with no animation :(

Comment: This works for me as is. One addition I'd make: call `layer.removeAllAnimations()` or quick repeated taps will make the border flicker out of step with the buttons' text.